# Routine Feedback

Tags: workout, program-review

Any thoughts on this routine?

Trying to lose a little fat and build muscle (180cm 74.5kg with belly fat).

I think im lacking shoulders, what can i do to improve this plan on that part?

Day 1. Upper

1. Bench Press: 3×5-8
2. Bent-Over Row: 3×5-8
3. Overhead Shoulder Press: 3×8-10
4. Lat Pull-Downs: 3×8-10
5. Seated Dumbbell Shoulder Press: 3×8-10
6. Seated Biceps Curl: 3×12-15
7. Tricep Cable: 3×12-15

Day 2. Lower

1. Romanian Deadlifts: 3×6-8
2. Leg Press: 3×6-8
3. Leg Curls: 3×8-10
4. Split Squats or Lunges: 3×8-10
5. Standing Calf Raises: 4×6-8

Day 3. Push

1. Incline Press: 3×6-8
2. Dumbbell Bench Press: 3×8-10
3. Chest Fly DB or Cable 3x10-12
4. Arnold Press: 3×8-10
5. Lateral Raises: 3×10-15
6. Lying Triceps Extension: 3×10-12

Day 4. Pull

1. Close Grip Pulldown: 3×6-8
2. Single Arm Lat Pulldown: 3x10-12
3. T-Row: 3×8-10
4. Rear Delt Fly Machine: 3×10-15
5. Barbell Curl 3×10-12

Day 5. Legs

1. Squats: 3×6-8
2. Barbell Hip Thrusts or Weighted Hyperextensions: 3×8-10
3. Leg Extensions: 2×10-12
4. Leg Curls: 2×10-12
5. Seated Calf Raises: 4×10-15

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you're lacking on your shoulders then a dedicated shoulder day could benefit you, it could be paired with another muscle group but always do shoulder first. Maybe also put it before chest in your weekly routine. You have 3 shoulder presses throughout the week and 2 on one day which could be a bit too much volume. If you opted for the dedicated shoulder, which is what I do, I'd recommend just one exercise for each part of the shoulder (front, side and rear delts). Stick to just 2-3 sets for each exercise but keep the intensity high by going to, or as close as you can to, failure on every set.

Another method I've started using recently which has been very effective for me is implementing myo-rep sets (which can be incorporated with any exercise for all muscle groups). The way I use it is going to failure on my first set and then on the second set, stopping 2-3 reps shy of failure, reducing the weight slightly and going again until almost failure. Do this 2 or 3 times until you finally fail on 50% or less of the original working weight.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify and based on the goal you gave, I am going to assume you are at the beginner level.

If this is not the case, then the only thing that you are missing is upper Trapezius. I would recommend some form of shrug. Which I would add on day 4.

If that is the case, I would recommend a simpler plan. A lot of the early gains are getting used to the motions of the lift. Only doing the motion once a week will slow those gains down. Below is a sample plan that tries to increase the repetition of exercises. Adjust sets/reps as needed.

Day 1: Push

1. Bench Press: 3x5
2. Incline Bench: 3x6
3. Chest Fly DB: 3x10
4. Arnold Press: 3x10
5. Lying Tricep Extension: 3x12

Day 2: Legs

1. Romanian Deadlifts: 3x5
2. Squats: 3x6
3. Leg Press: 3x8
4. Leg Curls: 3x8
5. Standing Calf Raises: 3x12

Day 3: Pull

1. Bent-Over Row: 3x6
2. Lat Pulldowns: 3x8
3. T-Bar Row: 3x8
4. Reverse Fly: 3x10
5. Lateral Raises: 3x10
6. Seated Bicep Curls: 3x12

Day 4: Push
Same as Day 1

Day 5: Legs
Same as Day 2

Note for most new lifters, I would also change it to a 3 or 4 day plan. Because when starting out it is easy to miss a day and then get discouraged. Fewer days allows for being able to make things up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).